# SDK[45] Nivel API 33 error <bluetooth_name>

Tags: android, react-native, expo

Good morning! I'm new to Expo, I'm trying to update the API level from 31 to 33, but I had to update some dependencies, when opening my app, this error appears here <bluetooth_name> is only readable to apps with targetsdkversion lower than or equal to 31

What am I using at the moment
expo: ^45.0.0
react-native: 0.68.2
react-native-gesture-handler: 2.8.0
expo-device: ~4.2.0
react-native-webview: 12.1.0[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnVwk.jpg)

I tried updating the react-native-gesture-handler and react-native-webview, but without success in opening my app.